# Basic Multivariable Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am working on a WebWork question which asks for the following:

---

Find the volume between the cone $y = \sqrt{(x^2 + z^2)}$ and the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4.$

---

I think I have worked out the limits of integration for a Cartesian Coordinates representation as: $\int_{-2}^{2} \int_{0}^{2} \int_{-2}^{2} dxdydz$. I think this because $x$ and $z$ must be bound between 0 and 2 because of the sphere equation conditions and $y$ is bound between 0 and 2 can't be negative since it's equal to the square-root of something (and also must satisfy the sphere equation).

However, I'm thinking that using spherical coordinates might make more sense to represent this problem since there is a spherical equation that is offered as a constraint. But I'm unsure how to translate this into spherical coordinates.

Any help would be appreciated for translating this into spherical coordinates.

Comment: Indeed, spherical coordinates are the way to go here. Do you know what there volume differential ($dV$) is in spherical coordinates? Do you know the equation for a cone in spherical coordinates? If you find both of these, you'll be good to go.

Comment: Your limits aren't what you want, since you are integrating over a rectangular box.

Answer (score 1):

Spherical coordinates are the easiest in this case. This is because your limits of integration for Cartesian Coordinates aren't as easy as you have them. What you have defines a box, but we want a cone shape. The limits of integration in Cartesian Coordinates will involve other $x$, $y$, or $z$ terms.

Spherical Coordinates are the best because of the simple representation of a cone and sphere, but you might have to change which axis you consider "up," as the cone is opening in the $y$-direction. Alternatively, you could just consider the equivalent volume between the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. These two equations translate into spherical coordinates as $\rho = 2$ and $\phi = \arctan(1) = \pi/4$. See if you can take it from there. Else, just ask.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please explain how you found out that $\phi = \arctan(1)$? I understand that $\phi = arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ however, I don't understand how you found the value of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ah. See, the formula for the azimuth angle is $\phi = arctan(z/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) = arctan(z/r)$, which makes sense if you consider the azimuth angle in a given cross section plane holding $\theta$ constant.

Comment: At this point, I have $\int_{?}^{?}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}r^2sin(\theta)dr d\theta d\phi$. I do not understand how to calculate the limits of integration for $\phi$.

Comment: Essentially, we want the area 'inside' the cone, so $\phi$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi/4$; straight up to half way till horizontal.

Comment: I tried to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}r^2 sin(\theta)dr d \theta d \phi$ and I got $\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$ which is the incorrect value. Please help me to understand where I have gone wrong.